# Looking for a dark fantasy book that featured a world of mutants

Tags: story-identification, mutant

In 1989, I read a book about a dark, post-apocalyptic world where mutants, whose descendants were engineered by scientists, now live alongside the surviving humans. I can't remember too much about it, but one chapter was quite striking. It featured a sailing ship that was powered by the flapping wings of slave vampires lashed to the masts.
There were a bunch of different kinds of mutants, such as centaurs and minotaurs.

Comment: Are you saying there are two different kind of mutants?

Comment: There were many different types of mutants - centaurs, minotaurs, vampires, etc. but the vampire slaves left a lasting impression!

Answer (score 2):

Is it maybe World Enough and Time by James Kahn?

[http://www.amazon.com/World-Enough-Time-James-Kahn/dp/0345327004](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345327004)

Comment: That seems to be the one, alright! I was going to read the following two books in the trilogy, but the reviews are pretty bad . . .

Comment: I've skimmed the bits of the book that happen on or by the sea - chapter 11 onwards - but I can't find any mention of the vampire slaves. Which chapter are the mentioned in?